# how to insert new data in a table using MySqlCommand with asp.net visual basic

Tags: mysql, asp.net, insert

I'm working with asp.net and visual basic, and I'm using mysql connector/net.

I created a code to show the data from a table and it works well.
At the same time, I created a code to insert new data, but it won´t work.

This is the code for mysql

```
Private _conexion As MySqlConnection
Private _adaptador As New MySqlDataAdapter
Private _tabla As New DataTable

Public Function crear() As Boolean
    Dim estado As Boolean = True

    Try
        conexion()
        _adaptador.SelectCommand = New MySqlCommand("select rut,nombre from empresas where usuario=27", _conexion)
        _adaptador.Fill(_tabla)
        _adaptador.InsertCommand = New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO empresas (`codigo`, `nombre`, `direccion`, `ciudad`, `rut`, `giro`, `usuario`) VALUES (NULL, 'GOOGLE', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '28')", _conexion)
    Catch ex As Exception
        estado = False
    Finally
        cerrar()
    End Try

    Return estado
End Function
```

And this is the visual basic code for the user interface:

```
Protected Sub btngrabar_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btngrabar.Click
    Dim conexion As New CConexion
    Dim tabla As New DataTable


    If conexion.crear Then
        tabla = conexion.tabla
        GVCompleto.DataSource = tabla
        GVCompleto.DataBind()
    Else
        MsgBox("Error al conectar la base de datos")
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Do not use dataadapter to execute INSERT query. You can directly use MySqlCommand object to execute INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE queries.
To execute, use MySqlCommand command= new MySqlCommand("Your insert query goes here")


command.ExecuteNonQuery()

Comment: It's still not working. What I did is:

    Private cmd As MySqlCommand

            cmd = New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO empresas (`codigo`, `nombre`, `direccion`, `ciudad`, `rut`, `giro`, `usuario`) VALUES (NULL, 'GOOGLE', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '28')")
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

Comment: Try replacing NULL to System.DBNull.Value